# Which types of cables are needed to connect RaspberryPi with Hx711 and 4 load cells?

Tags: pi-4

I want to create a weight scale using my RaspberryPi 4. I bought a Hx711 and 4 load cells.

I looked at many tutorials on the internet but none of them mentioned which types of cables are used to connect the RaspberryPi and the other components.
I'm pretty sure that I need jumper wires, but since there are 3 types (as per my research) I don't know which ones to get.

This is my Hx711:

[image: My Hx711]

4 load cells like this one:

[image: 4 load cells]

And this is the circuit I want to create:
(I'll use a RaspberryPi instead of an Arduino of course)

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

The jumper you need depends on the things you want to connect.

There are three types of jumper wire.

1. male-male:  use this if both things to be connected have sockets (holes).
2. female-female: use this if both things to be connected have pins.
3. male-female: use this if one thing has a socket and the other has a pin.

The Pi's extension header has pins and will always be a female end.

You will likely make some connections by soldering.  E.g. the load cell leads may be soldered to the HX711.

Really it comes down to your personal preference.

It's likely that you will need to solder headers to the HX711 for convenience.  I would use header pins rather then a header socket (a lot of modules might come with header pins loose in the bag to be soldered into place).